# How to Deploy/Publish SSRS Reports over the web?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How can I publish/deploy the SSRS Reports that I have build (using BIDS and Report Builder) over the website from where the user could just see the reports information such name & reports location and could head over to the specific report, click the search parameters (if any), click the "View Report" button and the report generates

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If this is for internal facing users, you can just use the functionality of the [Report Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147.aspx) website.

You can control user privileges with roles; the default **Browser** role will allow users to view items with a low level of access.

If you want to integrate SSRS reports into an external website, you can use the [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control to connect to a Report Server and render reports.

To get the names and locations of reports on a particular Report Server, you can access the [Report Server Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx), and call web methods like [ListChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listchildren.aspx) to get an idea of objects in the Report Server.